# How to test for redundant resource requests?

Tags: javascript, http, firebug

As I work on optimizing a website, I've been staring at the Net panel in Firebug to see if there are any resources (JavaScript, in particular) being requested more than once. (I recognize that the browser probably uses the cache in these cases, but it might cause some odd JavaScript effects such as a double-warning on a validation error).

But the Net panel is only as good as my spot checking. Is there any way to red-flag these redundant requests in a way that's easy to do and hard to miss? (It doesn't have to be Firebug, if you can do it effectively with wget, curl, chrome, or even IE I'll give it a shot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go one step better than this, check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html).

Comment: Interesting. It's not what I need at this moment, but it looks like something I want. ;)